# document is not under source control and nib shows as xml text

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode4, nib

since yesterday I´m getting "document is not under source control" when clicking on a nib file in the navigator. And instead of the graphical presentation I see xml.

I´ve been using the current version 4.3.2 (4E2002) since March 21st 2012. But this error came up first yesterday night. Restarting and cleaning the project didn´t help and restarting the mac didn´t help either. When switching to another project, I don´t have that problem. I´m not aware that I changed any preferences.

Any clues what´s wrong?

### Greetings from Switzerland, Ronald Hofmann

**Solution**

I found what was wrong: 'Show the version editor' was turned on. 
When turning it off the error is gone.
[image]
Ronald

Comment: change from Version Editor to First tab Editor its working fine...

Answer (score 1):

Try control-clicking on the nib file in the navigator and then go to "Open-As" and select Interface Builder - iOS. That should clear up your problem with it displaying as XML.

As far as it being under source control, is your project as a whole under source control? If so, what are you using?

Comment: I´m using Xcode4 (see tags) and there is no Interface Builder anymore and no, my project is not under source control. But anyway, I solved the problem, see image above.

Comment: "Interface Builder - iOS" is still a selection in Xcode4 when you control-click on a nib and select open-as. It is a remnant from the IB days, but it allows you to open it in different formats...try it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But this option is not available when 'Show the version editor' is switched on. And that was the problem. See **Solution** above.

Comment: Actually I had the same problem but with the xcodeproj document and all the project files. It turns out if you do a open with and then choose xcode you tell OSX that it is safe to allow full access to the files and thus other processes like git or svn can access them. It's a security thing in 10.7+ like Gatekeeper.